# How to escape forward slash in Word VBA Find?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have documents containing hidden markings like these

> <tag>**tag content**</tag>

The tags themselves use a hidden font, the content does not.
I need to find the tag content but the forward slash seems to cause issues

```vba
ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = True

Find.ClearFormatting
Find.Text = "<tag>*</tag>"
Find.Forward = True
Find.Wrap = False
Find.Format = False
Find.MatchWildcards = True
Find.IgnoreSpace = True
Find.IgnorePunct = True
Find.Font.Hidden = wdUndefined
Find.Execute
```

When I remove the forward slash of one of the tags (and the search string of course) it works fine.

I´ve tried `Find.Text = "<tag>*<\/tag>"` to escape it but that does not seem to work.
My MS Office language is set to english but the documents originate from a german version, not sure if that matters?

Comment: To better understand the use of wildcards see https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Word `<` and `>` are used as wildcards for the beginning and ending of a word. That's why you have to escape them as well

`\<tag\>d*\<\/tag\>`

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I should have been able to guess that but I just assumed `<` and `>` where fine because it worked fine when removing the forward slash. But now I guess it makes sense **why** that worked. It now even works without escaping the forward slash so do I actually need to escape it?